# How to find out list of objects used last year in IBM i

Tags: ibm-midrange

Is there any query to find out "How to find out list of objects in the system used last year in IBM i/AS400"

Comment: Take a look at the OBJECT_STATISTICS table function. 
 That returns a table with a LAST_USED_TIMESTAMP column. 
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajq/rzajqudfobjectstat.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of objects on the typical IBM i. While you can indeed search for the last use of all objects, the query will likely take longer than you want. Better to do 1 library at a time.

You can use this command to retrieve object descriptions into a database file which you can query:

```
DSPOBJD OBJ(LIBRARY/*ALL)        
        OBJTYPE(*ALL)           
        OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)        
        OUTFILE(LIBRARY/OBJUSED)
```

Or you can use the table function mentioned by @jweberhard like this:

```
select * from table (object_statistics('LIBRARY', '*ALL')) a
```

Note the upper case library name and '*ALL' in the SQL. This is important.

While you can use `*ALL` in place of `LIBRARY` in either option, that will cause the run to take a long time.

---

To get non system libraries you can use something like this:

```
select * from table (object_statistics('*ALL', '*ALL')) a
where objlongschema not like 'Q%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. With above query I got the list but now, is it possible to omit the Q starting libraries. I need an objects last used from all libraries except Q* starting libraries.